# Include SqlServerDriver on maven project

Tags: sql-server, maven, repository, odbc-sql-server-driver

I have this problem:
I have to connect to a sql server db using sqlServerDriver in my maven project.
The problem is: i can't find any repository that provide me the artifact:

```
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
```

I've read some suggestion about deploying it in it's own repository, but can i redistribuite this Microsoft artifact?
Or is there any other way? like physically include the jar on the project and then instruct maven to get the jar as a resource.. (but i haven't idea if this is possible and how to make it..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First question: "The Microsoft JDBC driver is freely redistributable under a separate Redistribution License that requires registration", [as stated on their site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx).
- Second question:

  - The artifact is not available via Maven Central, meaning you will need to have it deployed to your own repository (such as Nexus, Artifactory or the likes).
  - Alternatively, as an ugly hack which is strongly discouraged, you can have the library included in your project's directory and define a dependency to it with scope `system`. You can package it in your final artifact via the `maven-assembly-plugin` or `maven-shade-plugin`. (Just to re-iterate: this is highly discouraged).

Comment: Oh, that's right, i'm going to question the sistemist to get the redistribution license, thanks!